# Getting error on Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression could not be converted to string laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mysql-8.0, php-8.2

I am getting an error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to string for following code

```
$draft=$this->query->whereRaw('t.id IN '.\DB::raw("({$inner_query_draft->toSql()})"))->mergeBindings($inner_query_draft);
```

I have tried `ddSql` and `dump` but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Should

> $draft=$this->query->whereRaw

be

> $draft=$this->query()->whereRaw

note the query() brackets.

Comment: $draft=$this->query()->whereRaw with this it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is an error you ran into while upgrading to Laravel 10 from 9?

The result of `DB::raw()` can no longer be cast as a string like that:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#database-expressions

So the correct line would be:

```
$draft=$this->query()->whereRaw('t.id IN '.\DB::raw("({$inner_query_draft->toSql()})")->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar()))->mergeBindings($inner_query_draft);
```